# Suprising Babel error after upgrading a Node.js module (monaco-editor)

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, monaco-editor

I'm working on an React-based web application (created using CRA), so it uses Babel to transpile and pack our code and Node.js modules. Creating the production build worked fine until I upgraded the monaco-editor Node.js module from 0.20.0 to 0.21.2. After that an error started showing up, which is totally unexpected and probably caused by (valid) code changes in monaco-editor:

```sh
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/contrib/suggest/wordDistance.js
Error: <path>/node_modules/monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/contrib/suggest/wordDistance.js: unknown Expression of type "ClassExpression"
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

I'm pretty sure this is not a failure in the monaco-editor Node.js module and my web search brought me to some code that made me think this is an error printed by Babel. Beside others, I found this [pull request for Babel](https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/5341) which fixes a very similar error message.

There's no other information in the error message, so I cannot be 100% sure, and therefore I would also very much welcome anything I could use to get more context for this error message.

I created a minimal example which produces this behavior and allows to prove that the monaco-editor upgrade is the culprit: https://github.com/mike-lischke/babel-test.

But since this is valid JavaScript code, I supposed the real culprit is Babel, not being able to deal with the used syntax (or maybe I need a newer version, but since this is all integrated in CRA it's tricky to use newer versions of automatically installed components).

Comment: Which version of react-scripts and its related modules are you using? Could you perhaps show your `package.json`?

Comment: As a test, does `0.21.0` work or does it cause the same error? Did you change any other dependencies than `monaco-editor`? This definitely sounds like something in the dependencies downstream have changed - could be that one of your own dependencies is pulling in a version of some babel library that's incompatible with what monaco needs. One starting point could be to diff your `package-lock.json` between `0.20.0` and the first next version to cause the error, and see what's changed related to `@babel`.

Comment: There's only 0.20.0 and 0.21.2. I went back to 0.20.0 several times and it always started working again. I also had to upgrade `monaco-editor-webpack-plugin` and `monaco-typescript`. I checked package-log.json for changes and there was nothing related to babel.

Comment: If you nuke `node_modules/` and `package-lock.json`, then `npm install`, does it work?

Comment: That was the first thing I tried :-) Between all switches of the monaco-editor versions I removed node_modules and package-lock.json.

Comment: How frustrating! If the issue is the same as the one you linked, could try manually installing the latest versions of the related babel dependencies, namely `npm i @babel/plugin-transform-regenerator@^7.10.4 regenerator-transform@^0.14.2` - though I'm afraid if that doesn't work, I'm all out of ideas and can only suggest trying to create a very minimal project that reproduces the issue so we can take a closer look at what's happening.

Comment: By "we" you mean the BabelJS team? Shall I file a bug report on Github?

Comment: "We" as in the StackOverflow community :) You might, if you manage to make a small project that reproduces this, I suppose it's worth a shot opening an issue in the monaco-editor repo.

Comment: OK I created a mininal example to show the problem (see updated question) and reported an error against monace-editor. Fun fact: someone else had the same problem and opened an issue there just an hour ago :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time being there's no other way than to return to the previous version of Monaco editor.